# Matching of cells in excel

Tags: excel

It Sum of columns is storing in one cell and if I want the same answer to be printed in another cell, what is the formula to get this?

Comment: Your subject say Excel and you have tagged as Asp.net. Where exactly do you intended to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your sum is stored in B1 and you want same in C1 then you can do

> =B1

inside C1 cell

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want the value of cell A1 in cell B1. You would use this formula in B1:

```
= A1
```

In code you would write something like this (example in VBA):

```
Dim sht as Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet") //Or whatever your target sheet is
sht.Range("B1").Formula = "=" & sht.Range("A1").Address
```

Comment: Both of use took the same example :)